# how implement own blend function?

Tags: c++, c, rendering, blending, glblendfunc

I want to implement the following blend function in my program which isn't using OpenGL.

```
glBlendFunc(GL_DST_COLOR, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

In the OpenGL realtime test Application I was able to blend with this function colors on a white background. The blended result should look like http://postimg.org/image/lwr9ossen/.
I have a white background and want to blend red points over it. a high density of red points should be get opaque / black.

```
glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

for(many many many times)
glColor4f(0.75, 0.0, 0.1, 0.85f);
DrawPoint(..)
```

I tried something, but I had no success.
Has anyone the equation for this blend function?

Answer (score 1):

The blend function should translate directly to the operations you need if you want to implement the whole thing in your own code.

- The first argument specifies a scaling factor for your source color, i.e. the color you're drawing  the pixel with.
- The second argument specifies a scaling factor for your destination color, i.e. the current color value at the pixel position in the output image.
- These two terms are then added, and the result written to the output image.

`GL_DST_COLOR` corresponds to the color in the destination, which is the output image.

'GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA` is 1.0 minus the alpha component of the pixel you are rendering.

Putting this all together, with `(colR, colG, colB, colA)` the color of the pixel you are rendering, and `(imgR, imgG, imgB)` the current color in the output image at the pixel position:

```
GL_DST_COLOR = (imgR, imgG, imgB)
GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA = (1.0 - colA, 1.0 - colA, 1.0 - colA)
GL_DST_COLOR * (colR, colG, colB) + GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA * (imgR, imgG, imgB)
= (imgR, imgG, imgB) * (colR, colG, colB) +
  (1.0 - colA, 1.0 - colA, 1.0 - colA) * (imgR, imgG, imgB)
= (imgR * colR + (1.0 - colA) * imgR,
   imgG * colG + (1.0 - colA) * imgG,
   imgB * colB + (1.0 - colA) * imgB)
```

This is the color you write to your image as the result of rendering the pixel.